# How to add a secondary Y axis to a Plotly Express bar plot?

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, plotly-express

I would like to add a second Y axis to my bar plot bellow, that is the number of citizens in integer:
[image]

this graph was made using plotly:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(df, x="country",y="pourcent_visit",color="city",barmode='group')
# fig.add_hline(y=10)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Check [here](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/) - "Note: At this time, Plotly Express does not support multiple Y axes on a single figure. To make such a figure, use..."

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, there's no direct way to do this. But you can easily build a `Plotly Express` figure, grab the traces (and data structures) from there and combine them in a figure that allows multiple axes using `fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])`. With no provided data sample, I'll use the built-in dataset `px.data.tips()` that I'm guessing to a large part resembles the structure of your real world dataset judging by the way you've applied the arguments in `px.bar()`. Details in the comments, but please don't hesitate to let me know if something is unclear.

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# sample data
df = px.data.tips()

# figure setup with multiple axes
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# build plotly express plot
fig2 = px.bar(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker", barmode="group")

# add traces from plotly express figure to first figure
for t in fig2.select_traces():
    fig.add_trace(t, secondary_y = False)
    
# handle data for secondary axis
df2 = df.groupby('day').agg('sum')#.reset_index()
df2 = df2.reindex(index = df['day'].unique()).reset_index()

# 
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df2['day'], y = df2['size'], mode = 'lines'), secondary_y = True)

# fix layout
fig.update_layout(legend_title_text = 'smoker')

fig.show()
```